# Make my output (Canvas) show ONLY values between [0,1] (Java)

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt, intervals

Having the following `GridBagLayout` interface, with a `Canvas` type inside it, in order to represent random generated numbers normalized between [0,1] intervals:

[image: Interface with canvas]

I found the next problem: my canvas is showing values higher than 1, so it means that I can't see my normalized points(x,y); because they are too small with the actual canvas settings. This is what I'd like:

[image: Desired result]

As you see the points are obtained using the [Lattice structure](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Lattice-Structure-for-LCG-16807-0-2-31-1-1_fig1_228970502). How can I do it?

EDIT: Include code:

```
/**
 * Clase auxiliar empleada en interfazSimulacion.java para la representación de
 * nuestras simulaciones gráficas en el output. Hereda de la clase Canvas y
 * sobreescribe el método paint de dicha clase.
 * @author Fco Javier Perez Sanchez
 * @version 1.1
 * @since February 25, 2020
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Grafico extends Canvas{

public static int cantidadPuntos;
public static BigDecimal[] coordenadasX;
public static BigDecimal[] coordenadasY;

/**
 * Constructor principal del programa
 */

public Grafico(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    setBackground(Color.decode("#202421"));
}

/**
 * Método que establece la cantidad de puntos y las coordenadas de los puntos en X e Y.
 * @param cantidad  cantidad de puntos a generar.
 * @param X coordenadas en X.
 * @param Y coordenadas en Y.
 */

public static void getPuntos(int cantidad, BigDecimal[] X, BigDecimal[] Y){

    cantidadPuntos = cantidad;

    coordenadasX = new BigDecimal[cantidadPuntos];
    coordenadasY = new BigDecimal[cantidadPuntos];
    coordenadasX = X;
    coordenadasY = Y;
}

/**
 * Método que sirve para dibujar las simulaciones deseadas.
 * @param graphic objeto de tipo graphics usado para dichas simulaciones.
 */

@Override

public void paint(Graphics graphic){
    graphic.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    //graphic.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
    Graphics2D nuevoOutput = (Graphics2D) graphic;


    for(int i = 0; i < cantidadPuntos-1; i = i+2){

        Rectangle2D rect;
        rect = (new Rectangle.Double(coordenadasX[i].doubleValue()%this.getWidth(), coordenadasY[i+1].doubleValue()%this.getHeight(), 3,3));

        nuevoOutput.fill(rect);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it took a while for me to answer, I was rewriting my code with `JPanel` and `paintComponent(...)` as you suggested. Indeed, you are right, I should multiply my numbers by the width/height of the panel to get what I desired, not use modulo. It's only failing for the max value (1,1), it doesn't show in the painting. If you post your answer, I will give you as good anyways. Thank you a lot ;) @camickr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't help with your problem but, Swing applications should extend `JPanel`, not Canvas and do custom painting by overriding `paintComponent(…)`, not paint().

> I can't see my normalized points(x,y); because they are too small with the actual canvas settings.

If you have numbers between [0, 1] don't you have to multiply (instead of using modulo) those numbers by the width/height of the panel to get an x/y integer point to do the painting?

> It's only failing for the max value (1,1)

Well if the point starts at the bounds of the panel and extends for 3 pixels, then the point is painted outside the bounds of the panel and you won't be able to see it.

Maybe you need to multiply the normalized value by the (panel size - 3)?